# Joining tables for a comment list and determine if the user already upvoted/downvoted the comment

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I've been building a comment system for a project of my own and the way I currently determine if the currently logged user has voted (up or down) on the comment is not very.. smart. Right now I query the database everytime a comment is going to be displayed, which is not ideal for even 100+ comments per page. That means 100+ extra queries.

I tried using JOIN and LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN and I can't figure out how to do this by myself. Nothing that I tried gives me the result I need.

This is what I came up with but I can't figure out how to only merge the values where the user has voted.

```
$q_get_comments = $conn->prepare('
    SELECT comments.id,
           comments.parent,
           comments.subpage,
           comments.author_id,
           comments.author,
           comments.message_cut,
           comments.regdate,
           comments.points,
           votes_comments.user_id,
           votes_comments.user_name,
           votes_comments.comm_id,
           votes_comments.direction
     FROM comments LEFT JOIN votes_comments 
     ON comments.id = votes_comments.comm_id 
     WHERE comments.subpage= :subpage
     ORDER BY points DESC, regdate DESC');

$q_get_comments->execute(array(':subpage' => $sub_id));
```

and my tables are set up like this:

**Comments**

```
id parent subpage author_id author message message_cut ip regdate points up down
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  0      68      6         name   msg     <p>msg</p>  x  date    5      4  0
2  0      68      6         name   msg     <p>msg</p>  x  date    3      2  0
3  2      68      6         name   msg     <p>msg</p>  x  date    2      3  2
```

**Votes**

```
id  user_id  user_name  comm_id  direction
------------------------------------------
1   6        Chris      2        0
2   6        Chris      3        2
3   6        Chris      1        1
```

**votes.comm_id** matches **comments.id** and that's the way I tried to join the tables.

But I only want to join the results where *user_id = 6* and still show all the comments for the subpage, and only add.. say.. the *user_id* and *direction* to the according result in *comments*

**The result I need** with direction's value at the end to determine the vote status.

```
id parent subpage author_id author message message_cut ip regdate points up down direction
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  0      68      6         name   msg     <p>msg</p>  x  date    5      4  0    0
2  0      68      6         name   msg     <p>msg</p>  x  date    3      2  0    NULL
3  2      68      6         name   msg     <p>msg</p>  x  date    2      3  2    2
```

If direction is NULL, or blank field maybe, the user did not vote on this comment, if it has a value he did, or something along these lines.
( in the code direction 0 means a revoked/neutral vote, 1 means upvote and 2 means downvote, so if direction exists I can know that the user voted on this comment in some way, and I can show the right html for his vote )

Thank you in advance for any help or tips you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make 2 queries (sudo code, just showing sql, not the actual db calls) to select comments and votes, then merge the results in php:

```
$comments = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE subpage = :subpage');
$comments->execute(array('subpage' => $subpage_id));

$commentsById=array();
foreach($comments as $comment)
    $commentsById[$comment['id']]=$comment

$votes = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM votes WHERE user_id = :user_id AND comm_id IN (' . implode(",", array_keys($commentsById)) . ')');
$votes->execute(array('user_id' => $user_id)); // the user_id of the user

foreach($votes as $vote)
    $commentsById[$vote['comm_id']]['direction'] = $vote['direction'];

var_dump($commentsById);
```

Comment: I can't get this done. I understand the way you're saying that I should do it but I can't make it work properly. Mind spending a few more minutes to guide me? With your method I'm looking to have a comments array, a votes array and I need to attach the direction where the id from comments and comm_id from votes match.

Comment: @CristianBenescu Sure, what problems are you having?

Comment: Oh lord, I understood it wrong this whole time. It works fine after a few more tweaks. I started it again from your start code and it works fine now.  It feels like there's magic happening whenever I work with arrays. Thank you so much!

Comment: I edited your answer to fix a couple of things and it requires one more edit. If anyone else needs this, in $votes query it needs to be **..WHERE user_id = :user_id AND comm_id IN..** to personalize it to a single user

Comment: Glad you got it working - if you make that comment into another edit i will approve it, though note that `[]` is valid array creation syntax as of php 5.4

Comment: I see, when I put that in my text editor it said that it's invalid syntax and marked it red. Thank you once again for all the help, I couldn't take my head away from this problem and didn't advance with my project until I knew this fixed. On a ~115 comments list it reduced the comments php execution time from an average of 0.022 to 0.005, it's a huge improvement